# Change contents of a tab from a button in Kivy

Tags: python, tabs, kivy

I tried to access TabbedPanel.content.children[0] and remove the child and recrete a new child but it does not work. A note is that TabbedPanel.content is a TabbedPanelContent and not the ListView (in my case).

What I want to do is edit the contents of my listView. The app creates a button to generate data and two tabs, where the first tab create a listView of the data. If button pressed again it will remove previous ListView and insert new one.

How do I update contents of a tab? The code:

```
#test tabs

import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelHeader
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.properties import DictProperty
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton
from kivy.adapters.dictadapter import DictAdapter
from kivy.adapters.models import SelectableDataItem
from kivy.uix.selectableview import SelectableView
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.lang import Builder

import random

#templates kv for SelectableView+BoxLayout called CustomListItem
Builder.load_string('''
[CustomListItem@SelectableView+BoxLayout]:
    size_hint_y: ctx.size_hint_y
    height: ctx.height
    ListItemButton:
        text: ctx.text
        is_selected: ctx.is_selected
''')

class testTabs(BoxLayout):
    data = ListProperty([1,2,3,4,5])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(testTabs, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.listViewDict = {}
        #layout = GridLayout(rows = 2)
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        #buttonLayout = GridLayout(cols = 4)
        dataButton = Button(text = "press to load random data to tab 1")
        dataButton.bind(on_release = self.randData)
        self.layout.add_widget(dataButton)

        #create list
        list_item_args_converter = \
                lambda row_index, rec: {'text': rec['text'],
                                        'is_selected': rec['is_selected'],
                                        'size_hint_y': None,
                                        'height': 35}

        entry_dict = \
        {str(i): {'text': str(self.data[i]), 'is_selected': False} \
            for i in xrange(len(self.data) ) }

        self.listViewDict = entry_dict

        sortedDateEntriesList = sorted(self.listViewDict)
        dict_adapter = DictAdapter(sorted_keys = sortedDateEntriesList,
                                   data = self.listViewDict,
                                   args_converter=list_item_args_converter,
                                   template = 'CustomListItem')

        self.list_view = ListView(adapter=dict_adapter)

        ### Create tabs ###
        self.tabbedPanel = TabbedPanel()
        self.tabbedPanel.default_tab_text = "data tab"
        self.tabbedPanel.tab_pos = "top_left"
        self.tabbedPanel.default_tab_content = self.list_view

        tabbedPanelHeader = TabbedPanelHeader(text = "tab 2")
        tabbedPanelHeader.content = Label(text = "Hello world")

        self.tabbedPanel.add_widget(tabbedPanelHeader)

        self.layout.add_widget(self.tabbedPanel)

        self.add_widget(self.layout)

        #self.tabbedPanel.content.bind(children = self.foo)

    def foo(self, *args):
        print "############################in foo args:"
        print args
        tabbedPanelHeader = args[0]
        print tabbedPanelHeader.children

    def printContent(self, object):
        print "object:" +str(object) +"'s content: " +str(object.content)

    def printChildren(self, object):
        for child in object.children:
            print "object:" +str(object) +"'s child: " +str(child)

    #create list view
    def randData(self, *args):
        print args
        self.tabbedPanel.content.children[0].remove_widget(self.list_view)
        print "content tabbedPanel children:"
        print self.tabbedPanel.content.children

        tempData = []
        numValues = random.randint(10,20)-1
        for i in xrange(numValues):
            tempData.append(random.randint(1,30))
        self.data = tempData

        list_item_args_converter = \
                lambda row_index, rec: {'text': rec['text'],
                                        'is_selected': rec['is_selected'],
                                        'size_hint_y': None,
                                        'height': 35}

        entry_dict = \
        {str(i): {'text': str(self.data[i]), 'is_selected': False} \
            for i in xrange(len(self.data) ) }

        self.listViewDict = entry_dict

        sortedDateEntriesList = sorted(self.listViewDict)
        dict_adapter = DictAdapter(sorted_keys = sortedDateEntriesList,
                                   data = self.listViewDict,
                                   args_converter=list_item_args_converter,
                                   template = 'CustomListItem')

        self.list_view = ListView(adapter=dict_adapter)
        self.tabbedPanel.content.children[0].add_widget(self.list_view)

    def on_data(self, *args):
        print "on_data func. Data created:"
        print args

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return testTabs()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than mucking around with tabbedpanel.content, you can just keep a reference to your listview (or anything else you put in there) and modify it later.

For instance, in this example you store the listview as self.list_view. That means you can have a method that creates a new adapter then simply replace the old one to update the list. You can also do stuff like modify the `data` of the original adapter via the same reference.

Some (untested) example code would be something like:

```
def my_update_method(self, *args):

    new_dict_adapter = DictAdapter(data = whatever 
                                   # Obviously you have to make thi
                                   args_converter = list_item_args_converter 
                                   # You have to make this too, not included in
                                   # the example
                                   )

    self.list_view.adapter = new_dict_adapter
```

Comment: It seems to work updating the ListView contents (solves the problem but introduces another one), but in init func I start with 5 items and the created self.list_view is adjusted to that size I think. So if There is a lot of items it will not be able to scroll to the end of the list.

I thought of editing ListView.row_height property but do not know formula. Do anyone know how I can ajust it?

Another solution would be to create a new ListView every time and modify the content of tabbedPanel, so we are back to same issue again

Comment: Ah, so you mean when you update the listview with more items you cannot scroll to the end because it locks at the original height? I think that's an active bug with listview (it has been for a long time), that may already be fixed in kivy master, or will be soon if not. What version are you using?

Comment: Yes that is almost correct. I think ListView has some height param like scrollHeight or something (maybe ListView.row_height) that it sets based on the number of items I have in the ListView (5 in this case). So when I generate more than 15 items it stops at 15 items. It is possible to scroll more and view some more items but then it goes back to viewing 15 items at stop of scroll animation.

I use Kivy version 1.7.2 for windows.

Comment: In that case, you might be able to fix it by upgrading to the latest kivy from git (though I have no idea if this is hard on windows), as there's been some work on the area recently that may have already fixed the bug. Other than that, as you suggest above you can try to replace the widget - you can get its parent with `parent = self.list_view.parent then do `parent.remove_widget(self.list_view)` and create+add a new listview. That might work, though it isn't the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to change the data given to the listview, you shouldn't have to change te entire ListView for that. Look here https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/1321 this mentions a workaround till the data_changed branch for listview is merged in master. Eessentially just add this to your kv::

```
<ListView>:
    on_adapter: self.adapter.bind_triggers_to_view(self._trigger_reset_populate)
```

simply updating the data after that should show your changes in the listview.

For your issue with TabbedPanel all you need to do is ::

```
self.tabbedPanel.clear_widgets()
self.tabbedPanel.add_widget(self.list_view)
```

When you add widgets to the tabbed panel, it actually adds it to the content area. Similarly clear_widgets() clears the content area.

You could also do::

```
self.tabbedPanel.default_tab.content = self.list_view
self.tabbedPanel.switch_to(self.tabbedPanel.default_tab)
```

This is better as the linked content is updated and thus every time you change the tab appropriate changed content will be displayed.

The relevant Documentation in the docs::

```
Tabs and content can be removed in several ways:

    tp.remove_widget(Widget/TabbedPanelHeader)
or
    tp.clear_widgets() # to clear all the widgets in the content area
or
    tp.clear_tabs() # to remove the TabbedPanelHeaders

Warning

To access the children of the tabbed panel, use content.children:

    tp.content.children

To access the list of tabs:

tp.tab_list
```